# JQuery... change hover state on focus & Limit keyboard navigation tab area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm using a JQgrid in one of my projects (JFiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Yenros/ZzLdp/5/)). and would like

1.) the save & cancel button to highlight  when a user tabs to it (same as on mouse over). Found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052366/jquery-accomodating-both-hover-and-focus-together-mouse-and-keyboard) but can't seem to get it working

**FIX**: based on the answer provided by saratis

*after*

```
    <table id="theGrid" class="scroll">
    </table>
    <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align: center;">
    </div>
```

*add the following*

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).delegate('a', 'focus', function (event) {
            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); //Remove previous hightlights
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
        });

        $(document).delegate('a', 'focusout', function (event) {
            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); //Remove previous hightlights
        });
    </script>
```

2.) When the user tabs between the fields on the add modal, would it be possible to keep the focus on the modal. eg that when tabbing, the focus only loops between the controls on the modal itself

3.) I'm experiencing a weird issue with the pager not being centered, and not sure what the fix is. I see that an attribute of 106px gets added to pager_left td which is causing it, gut its a generated value, so i'm not sure how to override/disable it

**FIX**: `#pager_left{width:30%!important;}`

Would it be possible to achieve any of this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**:

```
$('.yourInput').bind("mouseenter focus mouseleave", 
        function(event) { 
          $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight'); //Remove previous hightlights
          $(this).addClass('highlight'); 
 });
```

I have tried to add this to the fiddle, but I think the modal dialog is written dynamically to the DOM, so the binding should occur after its being placed. And I do not know how to integrate that. Sorry.

For the **second** part, can be done, but it would be easier when you povided a sample, or even better, as JSDFiddle. -> Looking at it now, I wouldn't know. I'm sure a JS jQuery Guru good do it, but this is too much for me. Again sorry.

**Third**:
Some good news, don't know the cause, but: `#pager_left{width:150px!important;}`  does the trick.

Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Thank you once again, the css tip did the trick, i'll play around with the other two answers. Hopefully when i'm done here i'll be a sort of jquery (novice) guru :P

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to check if any of the modal fields already have focus. If they do, trigger a function on `keyup()` that checks whether the tab button was pressed (its keycode is 9).

Use this to limit the tab indexing to your form.

Comment: would it be possible to get an example, I'm pretty new to jQuery and not exactly sure how to to even attempt your solution..